# What limits are there to the word 'stepmother'?

Tags: meaning

The OED defines *stepmother* as:

*A woman who has married one's father after one's mother's death or divorce.*

In the case of a child such as Ruairi (Rory) Aldridge (character in the BBC radio soap -*The Archers*) he was the product of an affair that his father, Brian Aldridge, had with a *fancy-woman*,Siobhan, who later died. The affair was conducted whilst Brian was married to his wife Jennifer, who subsequently 'adopted' Ruairi and is bringing him up as her own child.

So what is the relationship between Ruairi and Jennifer? Can she be regarded as *stepmother*?

Comment: The BBC certainly regards Ruairi (Rory) as [Jennifer's stepson](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/4wGJsYGWMNnDn1NpG8DzjwY/jennifer-aldridge), and regards her as [his stepmother](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/3M48hJnRG5KY9MK9y6jlD0W/ruairi-donovan).

Comment: Imagine that. Siobhan. A flighty woman on _The Archers_.

Comment: @MattGutting But have the BBC got it right?

Comment: Once adopted, the proper form of address is "mother."

Answer (score 1):

Great question!  On reflection, I can see your point.  Because of the temporal aspect of this, I have come around to calling Jennifer the *adoptive mother*, and not the *stepmother*.  (I realize that in some cases, one person can be both.)

(In terms of the emotional commitment between Jennifer and Ruairi, I sometimes think Jennifer is more of a *housekeeper* than a mother to Ruairi!)

(By the way, *fancy-woman* sounds all wrong for Siobhan.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jennifer can be regarded as Ruairí's stepmother—at least according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stepmother):

> a woman that your father marries after his marriage to *or relationship with* your mother has ended

(emphasis added)

The OED appears to be assuming that the "relationship with your mother" must necessarily have been marriage.

Comment: I don't see how you can read that into the OED definition I quoted. Nor do I see how the Merriam-Webster definition necessarily encompasses a woman to whom one's father was already married at the time of one's birth.

Comment: Hm. Hmmm. Maybe you're right. Let me think on this one.